# when I try to get data from prisma on a dynamic page, I get an error

Tags: docker, next.js, prisma, nextjs-dynamic-routing, next.js13

I am creating a test website next js 13 and trying to deploy it using docker. Everything is fine in development mode, but when I use docker, I get an error. I noticed that in normal pages I can easily get data from the database, but when I try to get them in dynamic pages, I immediately get an error

here is a code

dynamic page

```
export default async function TypePage({ params }){

    const { type } = params
    let personality = await getTypeByName(type)
    let users = await getUsers()
    let comments = await getComments(type)
    let likes = await getLikes()
    likes = likes.likes
    users = users.users
    comments = comments.comments

    const slugPath = `./posts/${type}.md`
    let content1
    try {
        const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(slugPath, 'utf8')
        let { data: frontmatter, content } = matter(fileContents)
        console.log(personality)
        content1 = md().render(content)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log( 'ERROR IN MD' ,error)
        content1 = undefined
    }

    let color

    if (/NT/.test(personality.name)) {
        color = '#9075A0'
    }

    if (/NF/.test(personality.name)) {
        color = '#738D57'
    }

    if (/S/.test(personality.name) && /J/.test(personality.name)) {
        color = '#51A9AB'
    }

    if (/S/.test(personality.name) && /P/.test(personality.name)) {
        color = '#CCAD14'
    }

    return (
        <div className="type-page">
            {personality.name === undefined ? <div>undefined</div> : personality.name}
            <TypeBlock color={color} personality={personality} content={content1}/>
            <Comments comments={comments} type={type} users={users} likes={likes}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

prisma

```
export async function getTypeByName(typeName) {
    try {
        const type = await prisma.type.findUnique({
            where: {
                name: typeName.toString()
            }
        })
        return type
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR IN GETTYPEBYNAME' ,error)
    }
}
```

```
model Type {
  id String @id @default(uuid())
  name String 
  body String
  img String
  @@unique([name])
}
```

dockerfile

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm i 

# RUN npx prisma migrate deploy
RUN npx prisma generate
# RUN npm install next-auth @prisma/client @next-auth/prisma-adapter
# RUN npx prisma db pull

RUN npm run build --prod
# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build


# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/posts ./posts

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

error

```
ERROR IN GETTYPEBYNAME PrismaClientKnownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.type.findUnique()` invocation:


The table `main.Type` does not exist in the current database.
    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35024:13)
    at RequestHandler.handleAndLogRequestError (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34996:12)
    at RequestHandler.request (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34991:12)
    at async PrismaClient._request (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:36082:16)
    at async getTypeByName (/app/.next/server/chunks/719.js:43:22)
    at async TypePage (/app/.next/server/app/type/[type]/page.js:783:23) {
  code: 'P2021',
  clientVersion: '4.8.1',
  meta: { table: 'main.Type' },
  batchRequestIdx: undefined
}
undefined
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at TypePage (/app/.next/server/app/type/[type]/page.js:809:31)
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
  digest: '3508705048'
}
```

I spent two days to solve the problem, but in the end I didn't find anything

I tried to get data from different pages and everything was fine everywhere except for dynamic ones, I think the problem is in next js 13 because everything seems to be fine with docker and prism

Can someone help me please, what am i supposed to do??

Comment: Does the table Type exist in the Database. If it doesn't, you will need to create it either using `db push` command or `migrate dev` command